# create-react-app pausing indefinitely rather than creating a react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have started with react.js recently.
 I am currently using **node -v : v12.18.1**  and In order to make a react app I am using:
`npx create-react-app my-app` 

 
But on running this command something unexpected happens. My command prompt gets **paused indefinitely** as soon as things related to 
 `npm audit`
 are shown on the screen
 [Click here to see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdQqx.png)

I have tried waiting for an hour but nothing happened. As a result, I have to force stop the process by using `Ctrl+C` 
I have tried the following things:
1: clearing cache using `npm cache clean --force` and verifying it using `npm cache verify`
2: I have even tried re-installing node.js and uninstalling create-react-app using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and then installing it again.
3:I have even tried using yarn and npm but a similar error was shown in them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem arises due to the stalling of the command prompt. As mentioned in the question the terminal hangs and only node_modules folder is created and at the end most of the users end up terminating the process.
In order to solve this problem I opened the task manager and found a leaf symbol infront of my command propmt. However having this symbol is not a necessary condition.
**[Img: Showing a suspended process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM6Oy.jpg)**

Later I found that the process was suspended by the system due to some reasons.

I traced it down in the `Resource monitor` and resumed it.

**[Img:Resuming a process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfp0Q.jpg)**

***Happy Hacking !!!***

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

`npm install npm@latest -g`

Then close terminal.
Open a new terminal window and try `npx create-react-app my_app`

Comment: Delete the global node_modules folder